# Laravel belongsToMany() relation to work with all() or where() method and not just find()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called Images
I have another models called Categories

An Image can have many categories and also a category can have as many images. They are connected by `image_category` table, I have made the models in Laravel's Eloquent.

Now, I want to get all the categories of an image, I do this in `Image.php` Model:

```
function categories()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany("Category", "image_category");
}
```

Now I expect one of the following to work:

```
Image::categories()->get()->toArray();
```

Or:

```
Image:all()->categories()->get()->toArray();
```

The above does not work, I see the Laravel's documentation and I see all the examples are given by method find() :

```
Images:find(1)->categories()->get()->toArray();
```

My Problem: How should I use relation `categories()` with method `all()` or `where()`.

I can write the query directly in SQL, but I want to use Eloquent's features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want all images with `categories` nested in the result you should use eager loading:

```
$images = Image::with('categories')->get();
```

Or:

```
$images = Image::where('foo', 'bar')->with('categories')->get();
```